# Operating System not found with Ubuntu LTS 22.04

Tags: boot, usb, 22.04

Since the beginning of this month, I’ve had little to no success with installing the LTS version of Ubuntu 22.04. When the installation asks me to remove the USB and reset the system, “Operating system not found” appears on the screen at startup.

I’m trying this on a Dell Inspiron N7110 that originally ran Windows 7. The BIOS does not include a UEFI option nor does it allow me to toggle Secure Boot. For the USB, I formatted it to Ventoy on a 16GB drive.

Let me know what else I need to share in order to get this working. Thanks again in advanced.

Comment: So ... if the computer is BIOS then of course your USB for the Live Media uses BIOS? Rufus has always been the best tool to make the Live Media USB.

Comment: Make sure to set the first boot dev as hdd in bios after install ubuntu

Comment: There aren't enough details here to identify a solution. I suggest you start over. Here are the official instructions to [Install Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop). You should also [verify your download](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu) to make sure your installation media is not corrupted. If you still have problems, reference the tutorial when asking. Tell us exactly where you are stuck and include diagnostic information like the full text of errors or messages that don't align with the steps in the tutorial.

Comment: If a Windows 7 system over 10 years old, it may not run Ubuntu. You need a light weight flavor. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie And if nVidia, be sure to install restricted extra drivers as part of install.

Comment: First off **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** That said, you've already heard from some other long-time members. I'd also speculate (given that there's not a lot of information to go on) that you're particular HDD configuration is causing the Ubuntu installer to fail in partition allocation (particularly the boot partition). I'd suggest that when you attempt another reinstall that you choose the "Something Else" option and carefully set your partitions by hand (easier than it sounds, and you have this community available to help out). Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

I just experienced the same on an HP EliteBook 840 and it worked after changing the **BIOS-settings**. Restart the laptop and open the start up menue (for me, by pressing `ESC` while the laptop starts up). Look for `Boot options` and change boot mode from `Legacy` to `UEFI` which will add `OS Boot Manager` to the list of boot options. Since then, it works fine for me :)

Comment: > The BIOS does not include a UEFI option nor does it allow me to toggle Secure Boot.